# What are primary and secondary sides of PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers

I am designing a 2 layer PCB with components on both side of it. SMT components are one one side of PCB, but TH (through hole) components are on both sides. I have to go for mass production of say 300 pieces and for assembly. So, I was reading about component placement and minimum spacing. I need to understand something mentioned in guidelines ([Dave Jones](http://alternatezone.com/electronics/pcbdesign.htm) and [Spirent](http://irtfweb.ifa.hawaii.edu/~ao/Electronic/Peter_dump/Electronics/System/Text/PCBCADGuidelines.pdf)) called primary and secondary sides of PCB and secondary side components needs more spacing.

Also some very good source of guidelines for volume production will be very useful.

Comment: A link to the guidelines you mention would be useful here, to get the context of what you're quoting.

Comment: Link for PCB guidelines: http://irtfweb.ifa.hawaii.edu/~ao/Electronic/Peter_dump/Electronics/System/Text/PCBCADGuidelines.pdf
and 
http://alternatezone.com/electronics/pcbdesign.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary side is the side which has most of the components, especially the ICs. The most common soldering technique these days is reflow soldering, and it is simply easier to get precision temperature profiles on one side of the board only. The secondary side can also support components, but a) it's harder to control the temperature precisely, and b) gravity works against you as the solder paste begins to melt and the components on the underside of the board want to fall off.

Comment: To add: when components have to be mounted on both sides, the components on one side are often attached to the PCB with a glue dot, so that they don't fall off when the other side is reflowed.  The glue doesn't interfere with solder paste.  (Further reading: [NASA workmanship guidelines for glue dots](http://workmanship.nasa.gov/lib/insp/2%20books/links/sections/703%20Adhesive%20Application.html).)

Answer (score 0):

Given the references to "primary" and "secondary" in the document you linked, it appears that:

- the primary side could also be called the *top* side, and corresponds more exactly to the *component* side when doing a through-hole board with all components on the same side.
- the secondary side could also be called the *bottom* side, or more exactly the *solder* side, with a through-hole board.

The thing is: when designing for manufacture, you usually want to design the board with *all* through-hole parts on the *same* side. Because through-hole parts are soldered using a solder wave, and you can't use wave soldering on both sides without risking components from the other side falling (unlike reflow process used for SMT).

And that what is said in the document. I'm quoting: "The secondary side has the possibility of going through the wave so has a much greater restriction than the primary side". This means to me that the primary side does *not* have the possibility to go through the wave. Which means all through-hole parts must be on the same side (the primary one). SMT should be alowed on bith sides, though.

You may want to confirm this with the factory, but I'm afraid you may have to redesign your board according to this. There could, however, be exceptions to these rules, for example if you have a single through-hole component on the secondary side (like a connector), in which case it would be manually soldered anyway, rather than going through the whole wave soldering process.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the through-hole components will have to be placed manually on at least one side of the board.

If the assembler uses a solder wave one one side, it would be necessary to plug the holes for the parts which are to be placed later- this can be done by printing a mask which is later removed to open the holes out, but for only 300 pieces it maybe easier to place all the through-hole parts manually. Of course if you have just a few parts on the bottom and there are massive connectors with hundreds of pins that can be wave soldered then it may be worth it.

Since your SMT parts are only on the 'top' (primary) side of the board, no worries, but if they were on the bottom they would have to be glued on to withstand the wave soldering and it would be fairly hard on them (immersion in molten solder).

It's even supposed to be possible to stencil print solder paste for through-hole components, possibly in several swipes to get enough volume of paste into the holes, totally avoiding the solder wave, but that may not be feasible in small quantity.

Answer (score 0):

There are really no "guidelines" as a design engineer if you place tracks close together bad things can happen. This is dependent on voltage and other problems that arise such as solder bridges, there are calculations for this. There are also limits on manufactruability, typically 7mil but can be tighter depending on the PCB manufacturer. The thing that will place requirements on PCB's is regulatory specifications. Most countries require a regulatory body such as UL, TUV or CE. There is testing and requirements that have to be met before you can sell your product as well as a 16k$ to 8k$ fee for testing. One wishing to go through the regulatory process is best served by finding a consultant or minimum buying the specifications that apply to their product.

As far as High speed goes, it depends on what kind of transmission line you want, which will be determined by the termination in the IC. If you want a 50Ω transmission line on your board, then you will need to find the PCB material and thickness, then you calculate the trace width above the ground plane. I'd get a book and start studying.

Comment: can you name the book?

Comment: Get on amazon and find one that works for you.